# How to show duplicate as 1 else 0 in Excel?

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have a column containing customer numbers(column `A`), there might be some duplicates in the column. What I wanted to do is, have column to the right of customer number(column `B`) and show `1` (if the customer number appears more than once) or `0` ( if it is unique).

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write following formula in `B1` and stretch it down:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1,1,0)
```